# Can't edit fonts in WordPress Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, cornerstone

I am using the X-Theme with Cornerstone, and it's up-to-date. The website is [kelseycopywriter.com](https://kelseycopywriter.com)

For about a month, the fonts on my website have not been rendering correctly. The sizes are wrong, the font-family is incorrect, and so is the color. The settings in the theme haven't changed, and I've tried overwriting it with CSS. Nothing is working.

I believe this had to do with the Hummingbird optimization app after the most recent WordPress update. For a while, my images were not showing up. Somehow I fixed that, but now the fonts are having issues. I tried un-minifying everything and deleting hummingbird, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

when you use a plugin cache probably you have to clear the cache to see changes. If that not works try to disable each plugin one by one until problem is solved. To do that you can disable plugin from wordpress or if you have FTP access, you cane rename the plugin folder like _hummingbird and wordpress will not load the plugin. Keep me updated

Comment: I don't think renaming the plugin directory will stop it loading. Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Yes, it's wordpress structure, it doesn't recognize the plugin when you change directory name

Comment: In my experience it will still load it. The plugin name comes from the file header in the main php file. The directory name doesn't matter. Do you mean WP will deactivate the plugin?

Comment: yes, if you inside the plugin folder change the name of plugin for example _woocommerce, woocommerce will be disabled, or if you prefer you can disable plugin from wp-admin. Do this until you find the guilty plugin. If this not works, you can try to edit style.css of theme

Comment: Hi Drilon. Thank you for your suggestion. I've cleared my cache and already deleted the hummingbird app. But no change.

Comment: Which other plugins do you have installed? Try to disable other plugin one by one. I see your font is "Overpass",sans-serif, which font do you want to have?

Comment: @drilon, I want it to be overpass, with headings as merriweather. But even the proper colors aren't showing up.

Comment: Hi Elsie, can you tell me an example in your website, i'll check inspecting from the browser. Tell me which color you have set and which color you see